# access denied when using winjs.xhr for ftp

Tags: http, ftp, xmlhttprequest, winjs

I am writing some code for windows 8 that uses open data provided by the city of Vancouver. When I use the WinJS.xhr call on the data url:

```
ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/opendata/csv/weekendplayfieldstatus.csv
```

I get the exception:

```
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

Here is the function call:

```
var url = ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/opendata/csv/weekendplayfieldstatus.csv;
return WinJS.xhr({ url: url });
```

However, the very same call works for pretty much every other website I have tried. But, the rest have all been http and not ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE's `XMLHttpRequest` object (which WinJS.xhr uses) [doesn't support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/23/the-ie8-native-xmlhttprequest-object.aspx) ftp protocol so that's why you get an error.

Try using [BackgroundDownloader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx) class which supports ftp downloads.

Answer (score 0):

The XHR acronym stands for "XML **HTTP** Request". The protocol it supports is in the name.

Comment: Actually, it's not entirely true, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301280/can-ajax-use-protocols-other-than-http-or-https?lq=1, I was surprised too :)

Comment: @TadeuszWójcik Not part of the spec though. So you can't really complain when it doesn't work using a different protocol.