# get json data from a https webpage

Tags: json, https, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus

I like to get json data from a external webpage and use this data in my Xpages.
the external website have the protocol https.

so I can't use

```
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

http_request.open("GET","XX");
```

has anybody a hint for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you could use JSONP for your GET request:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/io/script.html

Answer (score 3):

Get it in backend with f.e. an XPage and `HttpURLConnection` class. This XPage can serve the JSON data to the client so you can use XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `XMLHttpRequest` object for Https protocol.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6301294/1029621

Comment: I believe the problem here is cross site scripting.